# non-metallic flex conduit permissible locations

Tags: electrical

Is it permissible to use non-metallic flex conduit in the garage or attic?

Specifically as a short distance "whip" between a disconnect and an appliance such as a water heater or an HVAC blower system.

[image]

Comment: I used that exact stuff to run electrical in my carport.  I see no reason why you couldn't use it in a garage or attic.

Comment: I don't recommend running it any farther than you have to.  It's a PITA to pull through, because tugging moves the conduit as well as the wires.

Comment: In an attic should be fine...in a garage would raise concerns about physical damage, but that's relatively easy to deal with, just make sure you can't run into it with a car :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing to reaching a prohibition is...

**356.12 Uses Not Permitted.** LFNC shall not be used as follows:
(1) Where subject to physical damage...

Answer (score 1):

Using it as a whip as you described would be OK. It's not likely they would be prone to damage. Just make sure to get the proper fittings and remember to run your ground wire along with the other wires. You'll have better luck if you run all the wires in the tubing before connecting the ends of the tubing to the box and appliance. Greenfield is always an alternative too.